# How to create a Expansion Tile from List<List<dynamic>> in Flutter?

Tags: arrays, list, dynamic, flutter, expansion

I have List> array and I need to create a Expansion Tiles.

My Expansion Tile must look like below format.

```
final List<Entry> data = <Entry>[
  new Entry('Varlıklar',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry('Vadeli Hesaplar',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('TRY'),
          new Entry('USD'),
          new Entry('EUR'),
          new Entry('GBP'),
          new Entry('TL TOPLAM'),
        ],
      ),
      new Entry('Vadesiz Hesaplar',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('TRY'),
          new Entry('USD'),
          new Entry('EUR'),
          new Entry('GBP'),
          new Entry('TL TOPLAM'),
        ],
      ),
      new Entry('Toplam',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('TRY'),
          new Entry('USD'),
          new Entry('EUR'),
          new Entry('GBP'),
          new Entry('TL TOPLAM'),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
  new Entry('Borçlar',
    <Entry>[
      new Entry('Vadeli Hesaplar',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('TRY'),
          new Entry('USD'),
          new Entry('EUR'),
          new Entry('GBP'),
          new Entry('TL TOPLAM'),
        ],
      ),
      new Entry('Vadesiz Hesaplar',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('TRY'),
          new Entry('USD'),
          new Entry('EUR'),
          new Entry('GBP'),
          new Entry('TL TOPLAM'),
        ],
      ),
      new Entry('Toplam',
        <Entry>[
          new Entry('TRY'),
          new Entry('USD'),
          new Entry('EUR'),
          new Entry('GBP'),
          new Entry('TL TOPLAM'),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),

];
```

The data that comes from server is look like as shown below. I am taking first array value and assign to above format as an example;

- 2 means Vadeli Hesaplar,
- 142980 next to "TRY"
- 20042 next to "USD"
- 65912 next to "EUR"
- 0 next to "GBP" and
- 758201 next to "TL TOPLAM"

**So my question is, How to create a Expansion Tile from List> in Flutter?**

```
[
    [
        2,
        142980,
        20042,
        65912,
        0,
        758201
    ],
    [
        1,
        2404,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        2404
    ],
    [
        9,
        145384,
        20042,
        65912,
        0,
        760605
    ]
]
```